# curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL AND HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: bash, curl, syntax

I have a problem with this code. It states that there is a URL issue but I don't see that as right. I am not responsible for the server though. I just wanted to test some IoT properties with basic linux commands.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=Client secret
c=Custom domain
b=Client id:
#!/bin/bash
response=$(curl -X POST --user $b:$a "https://${c}.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials" -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
token=$(jq -r '.access_token' <<< "$response")
secondsValid=$(jq -r '.expires_in' <<< "$response")
refreshToken=$(jq -r '.refresh_token' <<< "$response")

for i in  {1..4}

do
        declare -i TIME
        TIME=$(date +%s)
        TEMP=$(sensors -j | jq '."cpu_thermal-virtual-0"."temp1"."temp1_input"')
        curl -i -k -X POST -H "Authorization: $token"-H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "id":"2","timestamp":"'${TIME}'","data":"'${TEMP}'"}' https://dv7knsjzph.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/boxtronic-devices/2/data/
        sleep 1
        echo "$refreshToken"
        echo "$secondsValid"
        echo "$TIME"
done
```

Anyone knows why I am getting the error ?

Comment: --user "$b:$a"...

Comment: Does not seem to be the problem otherwise I would've been noticed about it through https://www.shellcheck.net/ 
Can this have something to do with the server or that the URL is corrupt ?

Comment: I had a space problem after  `$token"` and hat to put a space. Although the Errors had nothing to do with the syntax concretely ..